# BxSlider active dot not aligning with the rest of the dots

Tags: html, css, bxslider

I have the following site [here](http://astmaochallergilinjen-dev.indegene.com/sv-se/), when i click on any on the dots on the carousel, the active dot moves up by a few pixels , in the dev tools if i remove the active class, its aligned back properly , i have not sure whats causing this as the only property i have attached to the `.active` class is the following:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover, .bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active, .bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:focus {
    background: #0e2240;
}
```

the padding , margin , height, width of the dots remain the same.

The HTML of the bxSlider controls is the following:

```
<div class="bx-pager bx-default-pager">
        <div class="bx-pager-item">
            <a class="bx-pager-link active" data-slide-index="0" href="">1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="bx-pager-item">
            <a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="1" href="">2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="bx-pager-item">
            <a class="bx-pager-link" data-slide-index="2" href="">3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am unable to debug as to why this moving of positioning is happening, can somebody please point me to the right direction ?

Screenshot of the bug:

[image]

**EDIT**: it does't seem to be a problem with `inline-block` as if i remove the `.active` class, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give only `vertical-align:middle` to `.bx-wrapper .bx-pager-item` class.

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager-item {    
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check the styling

```
.bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {}
and
.bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {}

has same css except background-color
```